# Bounded operator from $H^1$ to $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

I am working through the nice Finite Element notes by Douglas N. Arnold at the moment. They can be found [here](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold//8445-8446.14-15/notes.pdf). A teeny tiny detail in the proof of Lemma 7.4 gives me a headache and I am looking for some advice.

We consider a triangle $T$ with an edge $e$. We define $P_e:L^2(e) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the projection of a function to its average value.
Now we are considering the operator \begin{align}\hat{P}:~&H^1(T)\rightarrow L^2(e)\\&\phi\mapsto\left.\phi\right|_e-P_e(\left.\phi\right|_e).\end{align}
The notation $\left.\phi\right|_e$ means the restriction of $\phi$ to $e$.

On page 114 in the first line of the proof to Lemma 7.4 it is stated that this operator is bounded (and linear) but I can't see a way to bound this nicely in $H^1$ norm $||\cdot||_{H^1}=\text{max }(||\cdot||_{L^2},||\frac{\delta\cdot}{\delta x}||_{L^2})$. The derivative in the norm is meant in the weak sense.

Note that it should be a projection (i.e. boundable by 1) if one follows the proof further.

Any ideas or literature recommendations?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you familiar with the trace theorem?

Comment: @themaker This gives me the boundedness of the restriction but not the boundedness of the whole operator, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: right, but then you just need to prove that the operator $\phi \in L^2\rightarrow P_e(\phi) 1 \in L^2$ is bounded

Comment: The trace theorem bounds the restriction, which means it remains to show that $P_e$ is bounded. But this is not difficult; it follows from the "Cauchy-Schwarz with 1" trick, among other approaches.

Comment: @Ian@themaker Thanks. How could I miss this - feel free to post this as answer and I accept it. Otherwise I will answer the question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restriction part is bounded by the trace theorem. Now it remains to prove that $P_e$ is bounded. This follows from the common "Cauchy-Schwarz with 1" trick:

$$|P_e(\phi)| = \left | \int_e \phi \cdot 1 \right | \leq \| \phi \|_{L^2(e)} \| 1 \|_{L^2(e)} \leq \| \phi \|_{H^1(e)} m(e)^{1/2}$$

where $m(e)$ is the measure of the edge $e$.